# OpenCV pattern recognition

Tags: opencv

I am going to do pattern recognition using OpenCV. The example of image is as such https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSaiAjNCczXwa9oFeFoqo8qahdZmpaQ9qu4qbBIxIBm7zTpP48.

Besides template matching, is there any other method to track pattern? Now I am using film inside the diskette to filter out all the thing except the light. And I planned to use LED to form a special pattern. I want to detect whether the pattern exist in the camera. The reason I do not want to use template matching is the algorithm of template matching is too heavy to run on Raspberry Pi.

Comment: What about the `feature matching`?

Comment: template matching, feature matching, chamfer matching, machine learning. There are many ways that try to detect patterns, each one has its own strengths and weaknesses. If your templates are special and limited, there might be very good and efficient specialized solutions.

Comment: @Micka Actually now I am using film inside the diskette to filter out all the thing except the light. And I planned to use LED to form a special pattern. I want to detect whether the pattern exist in the camera.